# Resize and crop image and keeping aspect ratio NodeJS & gm

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I've been trying to create some thumbnails using the `gm` package from NodeJS, but I'm out of lucky. I need to resize images bigger than 600x600 (could be any width/height, starting from the given one) but when I pass the size to gm, it creates an image that doesn't have the same size I requested.

For example, given this code, I assume that running `node app /path/to/image.png` I'll receive an image with size of 200x100, but instead I got, say, an image of 180x100 or 200x90...

```
gm(fileLocation)
    .thumb(200, 100, 'processed.' + process.argv[2].split('.').pop(), function() {
        console.log("Done!");
    });
```

I've also tried with the resize option. There's even an option to force the size, but the aspect ratio of the output goes horrible...

```
gm('/path/to/image.jpg')
    .resize(353, 257)
    .write(writeStream, function (err) {
         if (!err) console.log(' hooray! ');
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with `imagemagick` package for NodeJS: https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick

```
im.crop({
    srcPath: process.argv[2],
    dstPath: 'cropped.' + process.argv[2].split('.').pop(),
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    quality: 1,
    gravity: 'Center'
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('resized ' + process.argv[2].split('/').pop() + ' to fit within 200x200px');
});
```

---

**Update:** Please note that the [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick) package hasn't been updated in quite a long time. Please consider [Freyday's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25083756/1012139) since it's most up-to-date.

Answer (score 115):

To achieve a resized, cropped image with a center gravity with the `gm` module, you can use something similar to this:

```
gm('/path/to/image.jpg')
  .resize('200', '200', '^')
  .gravity('Center')
  .crop('200', '200')
  .write(writeStream, function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log(' hooray! ');
  });
```

The `'^'` argument on the `resize` function will tell GraphicsMagick to use the height and width as a *minimum* instead of the default behavior, *maximum*. The resulting resized image will have either the width *or* height be your designated dimension, while the non-conforming dimension is larger than the specified size.

Then `gravity` function tells GraphicsMagick how the following `crop` function should behave, which will crop the image to the final size.

You can find detailed documentation for the GraphicsMagick options used by the `gm` module here: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without external libraries (except by imagemagick) is create your own solution:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

resize = function (image) {
  var cmd = 'convert ' + image.src + 
  ' -resize ' + image.width + 'x' + image.height + '^' + 
  ' -gravity center -crop ' + image.width + 'x' + image.height + '+0+0 ' +
  image.dst;

  exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

And then call it:

```
resize({
    src: sourceFile,
    dst: destinyFile,
    width: 320,
    height: 240
});
```

It will allow your custom parameters of quality, crop, watermark, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Two things...

1) https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick - This package is no longer supported I would recommend the original package you were using.

2) The reason it's not resizing is that the .resize function takes in a string, not an integer.  It should be... **('353', '257')**

```
gm('/path/to/image.jpg')
    .resize('353', '257')
    .write(writeStream, function (err) {
         if (!err) console.log(' hooray! ');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Jimp package for Node.js https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp. Which is better than gm I think. It does not require any dependencies. I tried to use gm before but I was not able to install dependencies for gm. End up I used jimp and everything worked  fine.

```
   Jimp.read('lenna.png', (err, lenna) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      lenna
        .resize(256, 256) // resize
        .write('lena-small-bw.jpg'); // save
    });
```