# ImageMagic crop size is incorrect using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, imagemagick

I am using imageMagic module to crop image here is my code:-

```
var imageMagick = require('imagemagick');
 imageMagick.resize({
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    strip: false,
    srcPath: options.uploadDir + '/' + fileInfo.name,
    dstPath: options.uploadDir + '/' + version + '/' + fileInfo.name
}, finish);
```

it is working fine and crop the image but problem is when I set the size 50x50 
but when image cropped I got the image size 50x38. I don't know what is the issue.
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: What are the sizes of original image?

Comment: @Michelem its 1024x768

Comment: So you can't resize it to 50x50 maintaining the aspect ratio

Comment: @Michelem any way to do this any other library etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

There is also a better method to do everything with a single statement:

```
imageMagick.resize({
    srcData: img,
    strip: false,
    width: 50,
    height: "50^",
    customArgs: [
        "-gravity", "center", "-extent", "50x50"
    ]
}, finish);
```

---

If you need a square from a rectangle you should first of all, crop the image at the size of the minimum side.

For example, if you have an image of 1024x768, find the width and height, then find the minimum side (768), then do a crop like this:

```
imageMagick.crop({
    width: 768,
    height: 768,
    srcPath: options.uploadDir + '/' + fileInfo.name,
    dstPath: options.uploadDir + '/' + version + '/' + fileInfo.name
}, finish);
```

Then you can resize it to a square like 50x50:

```
imageMagick.resize({
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    srcPath: options.uploadDir + '/' + fileInfo.name,
    dstPath: options.uploadDir + '/' + version + '/' + fileInfo.name
}, finish);
```

I think you can chain `resize` and `crop` in a unique statement

Comment: yes now m already using this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591536/resize-and-crop-image-and-keeping-aspect-ratio-nodejs-gm thanks for your help :)

Comment: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/10/node-express-imagemagick-square-resizing/ thanks